# 404 page doesn't show when accessing a missing file in a static directory

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, static-files

I'm working on porting my blog from GitHub pages to Google App Engine. I've set up my app.yaml as follows.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
version: 5
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /api/.*
  script: main.app

- url: /
  static_files: src/_site/index.html
  upload: src/_site/index.html

- url: /(.*)/
  static_files: src/_site/\1/index.html
  upload: src/_site/*.*

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: src/_site/\1
  upload: src/_site/(.*)

error_handlers:
- file: static/404.html
```

You can get to my 404 page directly by going to http://joshuasnidercom.appspot.com/404.html and you can get to by accessing a missing page that the flask app handles like http://joshuasnidercom.appspot.com/api/invalidurl, but going to any page that is covered by the static files like http://joshuasnidercom.appspot.com/nonexistentpage just shows a `Error: Not Found The requested URL /nonexistentpage was not found on this server.` error.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Is static/404.html in the root of the project  and uploaded with main app ?

Comment: It is and it should be. I've also tried `templates/404.html` (so it would be the same as the working flask 404) and just tried putting it in the root as `404.html` on my dev server. Neither worked. Is there a way to test if a file is uploaded with the main app?

Comment: Do you mean it didn't work on the test server ?, upload in verbose mode and it should show you that the file is deployed.  I usually leave the default error files in the root directory of the app. (Remember to change app.yaml accordingly)

Comment: Actually stepping back and looking at what you are doing I really think this may not do what you expect.  Your main handler will capture any 404.  The error handler is only for uncaught exceptions.  If your main handler raises an exception on a 404 then this handler would be used.  It's normally used for system level errors etc..

Comment: I meant it didn't work when running with `dev_appserver.py` on my local machine. I just uploaded a version changed to have the 404 handler in the root and the deployed app's behavior is still the same. The verbose output says that it "processed" 404.html and doesn't mention any errors. Personally, I would've thought the error handler in my main.py would've been called when it couldn't find it in the static directory, but adding a print statement to that error handler and running `dev_appserver.py` only prints when I try in the /api/ directory.

Comment: No it's the other way around.  Path matches are performed in the order defined in app.yaml.   Finally if an exception is raised and not handled anywhere then the static handler will be presented. In other words it is the very last thing in the chain.  You app handler `/(.*)` will match everything. So in your case only uncaught exceptions will go to the static handler.

Comment: You need to perform 404 handling in you app, or if you encounter a 404 and don't want to present the error through the app raise an exception.

Comment: But that static handler will be show for any uncaught exceptions not just a 404.  For instance if google is having a problem, you have a bug in your code that is not handled you will get that static error page. So making it a 404 error page is probably not the correct thing to do.

Comment: @TimHoffman: I guess that makes sense, I'll see if I can switch the ordering of my app.yaml. But that still doesn't explain why if you try to go to http://joshuasnidercom.appspot.com/nonexistentpage, you don't actually see my 404 page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104695/discussion-between-joshua-snider-and-tim-hoffman).

Comment: It does actually.  error handler has nothing to do with order.  Its a last resort and you app will get everything as I pointed out earlier.  `/(.*)` this means everything not caught earlier will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create an error handler in your views file.
You can do this with the following code:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html"),404
```

You can also replace 404 with 500, 403, etc,for other errors.

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to do what Tim Hoffman suggested and make sure that all of my static directories were handled first, so if they had a 404 it would fall through to main.app and use the 404 handler it already had.